# Regular expression: how to match words preceded and followed by a specific chars sequence and containing some other chars

Tags: regex

I'm using a sort of bookmarks on a text. These bookmarks are so structured:
(# + field + #)

"Field" must contain only alphabetical chars (A-Z and a-z, not numbers or other chars).

I need to match words not satisfying this rule.

So, consider the following examples:

1. (#CompanyName#)
2. (#Company_Name#)
3. (#Company5Name#)

Only the first one is correct but I have to match the other 2 cases.
The pattern to match the first one is:

```
(\(\#)[A-Za-z]+(\#\))
```

To match the wrong cases I need something like this:

```
(\(\#)[^A-Za-z]+(\#\))
```

But this doesn't work correctly.

Can anyone suggest me how to get it working?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
\(#[^#]*?[^A-Za-z#]+[^#]*?#\)
```

Comment: Make sure to escape the outer parenthesis (or remove them).  Otherwise `[#CompanyName#]` looks valid to it.  The inner ones serve no purpose.  If they don't contain a # each, then the whole match failed.

Comment: It seems almost correct but it also catches the following case:
(#CompanyName#) - (#Address#)

Comment: @speednick What about now?

Comment: Great! Now it seems to work perfectly, thank you so much alestanis!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
\(#.*?[^A-Za-z].*?#\)
```

`\(` - escaped (
`#` - hash
`.*?` - zero or more wild-cards (non-greedily)
`[^A-Za-z]` - a single invalid character
`.*?` - zero or more wild-cards (non-greedily)
`#` - hash
`\)` - escaped )